# ExoPlayer clearkey issue

Tags: android, exoplayer, mpeg-dash

I am unable to play this clearkey sample stream with ExoPlayer. It is working fine in [JW Stream Tester](https://developer-tools.jwplayer.com/stream-tester). Can anybody try and let me know if it is working on your side?

Stream Url - https://cdnapisec.kaltura.com/p/2433871/sp/243387100/playManifest/protocol/https//entryId/1_pgssezc1/format/mpegdash/tags/mbr/f/a.mpd

Clearkey ID - a07c5d499dcead0fb416fed5913967be

Clearkey Key - caee457911302478487e6680bf0b3d1b

My code is working fine as other streams are working normally.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.